# Run a Java spark program parallel locally

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I'm new with spark
I'm trying to run the example JavaWordCount form spark git repo locally. The SparkSession looks like:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local[*]")
        .appName("JavaWordCounter.com")
        .getOrCreate();
```

although my cpu have 12 threads. the Program runs on just one

I have tried with SparkConf. the parallelize works good with List:

```
List<String> inputData = new ArrayList<>();
        inputData.add("WARN: Tuesday 4 September 0405");
        inputData.add("ERROR: Tuesday 4 September 0408");
        inputData.add("FATAL: Wednesday 5 September 1632");
        inputData.add("ERROR: Friday 7 September 1854");
        inputData.add("WARN: Saturday 8 September 1942");

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("newSpark").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<Integer> myRdd = sc.parallelize(inputData);
```

but when the inputData is a local file

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("newSpark").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> inputData = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/names.txt");
JavaRDD<Integer> myRdd = sc.parallelize(inputData);
```

I get the following error:

```
java: no suitable method found for parallelize(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<java.lang.String>)
    method org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<T>parallelize(java.util.List<T>,int) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<T>parallelize(java.util.List<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.List<T>))
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of `sc.textFile("src/main/resources/names.txt")` already returns an `JavaRDD<String>`, which is already a distributed obect by itself.

Trying to `sc.parallelize` on that RDD does not really make sense: it would be like trying to make a distributed object out of an object that is already distributed.

If you want to turn your `JavaRDD<String>` into `JavaRDD<Integer>` you can use the `.map` function, something like the following (I never use the Java API so forgive me for possible syntax errors):

```java
JavaRDD<String> inputData = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/names.txt");
JavaRDD<Integer> myRdd = inputData.map(x -> x.toInt());
```